# Prove an additive function has the property $f(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let
$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an additive function, that is for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

> Prove $f(0)= 0$

I'm a little rusty on proofs. Can I just say suppose $x=0$ and $y=0$,
$$f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y)$$

$$f(0+0) = f(0) + f(0)$$

$$f(0) = 2f(0)$$

$$f(0) = 0$$

I have no idea if that's the right process at all. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: You are indeed correct!

Comment: Sounds right to me...........

Comment: Why  are you unsure? This is obviously correct.

Comment: However, you need to improve the way you write. For example: " for all x, y is an element of the real numbers " is ungrammatical and awkward. Simply say " for all reals x, y " or " for all x, y in R ".

Comment: You could also just take y= 0.  f(x+ 0)= f(x)+ f(0) so f(x)= f(x)+ f(0) and, subtracting f(x) from both sides, f(0)= 0.  Now, use that to prove that f(-x)= -f(x)!

Comment: I don't understand that it is a proof. $f(0) = f(x+y)$ does not necessarily mean that $x=0$ (and/or $y=0$).